# General form of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{i}\right)$ and $\prod\limits_{i=2}^{k-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{i}\right)$

Tags: summation, products, trigonometric-series

I am trying to find the general term for the following series:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{i}\right)$$

and

$$\displaystyle\prod_{i=2}^{k-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{i}\right).$$

I tried using the complex form of the sine function, but I failed to simplify it. Reviewing many posts I found examples of form $\sin(i\pi)$ but not of form $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{i}\right)$

I don't have much experience in the area, but a good explanation would help me a lot. I appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you should expect to be able to find an elegant closed form for those expressions. For instance, in the case of $k=9$ in the product you would already have one of the factors equal to $-\sin(\frac{2\pi}{7})$, which does not look very nice...

Comment: For the product, as $k$ gets higher and higher, it tends towards $0$. It is also only $0$ for any $k$ that is prime (and $>2$).

Comment: Notice that if we make the integral from $1$ to $k$, we just have $$\pi  k (\text{Ci}(k \pi )-\text{Ci}(\pi ))$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the summation$$S_k=\sum _{i=1}^{k-1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{i}\right)$$ it is interesting to compare it to
$$I_k=\int _{1}^{k} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{i}\right)\,di=\pi\,  k\, (\text{Ci}(k \pi )-\text{Ci}(\pi ))$$ where appear the cosine integral function.

The asymptotics
$$I_k =-\pi \, \text{Ci}(\pi )\, k+(-1)^{k+1} \left(\frac{1}{\pi  k}-\frac{6}{\pi ^3 k^3}+\cdots\right)$$ and $-\pi \, \text{Ci}(\pi )\approx -0.231435$ which is almost identical to the result of the regression in my "non-answer".

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer.*

If we consider
$$S_k=\sum _{i=1}^{k-1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{i}\right)$$ looking (from far away) at a plot of it for large values of $k$, it really looks like a straight line. A quick and dirty linear regression $(2 \leq k \leq 1000)$ with no intercept gives $(R^2=0.9995)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -0.231423 & 0.000163 & \{-0.231743,-0.231102\} 
\end{array}$$

Extrapolated to $k=10000$ this model would give $-2314.23$ while the exact value would be $-2305.89$ which is not so bad.

Concerning the product
$$P_k=\prod _{i=2}^{k-1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{i}\right)$$ for large values of $k$, its logarithm looks to be very linear with $k$.